# Read excel file in spyder but some data missing

Tags: python, excel, spyder

I am a new in python and is trying to read my excel file in spyder, anaconda. However, when I run it, some row is missing and replaced with '...'. I have seven columns and 100 rows in my excel file. The column arrangement also quite weird.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

print("        Comparing within 100 Airline         \n\n")

def view():
    airlines = pd.ExcelFile('Airline_final.xlsx')
    df1 = pd.read_excel("Airline_final.xlsx",sheet_name=2)
    print("\n\n 1: list of all Airlines \n")
    print(df1)
view()
```

Here is what I get:

```
18       #051                         Cubana                  Cuba
19       #003                     Aigle Azur                France
20       #011                    Air Corsica                France
21       #012                     Air France                France
22       #019               Air Mediterranee                France
23       #050                        Corsair                France
24       #072                            HOP                France
25       #087                           Joon                France
26       #006                     Air Berlin               Germany
27       #049              Condor Flugdienst               Germany
28       #057                      Eurowings               Germany
29       #064                       Germania               Germany
..        ...                            ...                   ...
70       #018                   Air Mandalay               Myanmar
71       #020                        Air KBZ               Myanmar
72       #067        Golden Myanmar Airlines               Myanmar
73       #017                      Air Koryo           North Korea
74       #080                   Jetstar Asia             Singapore
75       #036                Binter Canarias                 Spain
76       #040                      Canaryfly                 Spain
77       #073      Iberia and Iberia Express                 Spain
```

[image]

Comment: just a suggestion, wouldn't you be better off exporting a CSV, and read the CSV file?

Comment: The `...` that you see means that there is more data between `head` and `tail` and it has been loaded. As for the column arrangement that is just internal order, your file is intact.

Comment: @zipa is there any way I can display all the data without the  ...  ?

Comment: @JephefnieGoh Please accept the answer below if it helped you with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the whole dataframe use:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df1)
```